# How to combine sql queries where one query uses the MIN function

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a read-only firebird database from which I want to extract data. In MS-Access it's very easy to get the data I want using three simple queries in which the output of each query is the input to the next one. Now I want to program this in PHP and to keep it on one line I want to combine these three queries in one but I can't figure it out.

The first query gives me all the dates starting today which are in my company planning (max 1000 lines). As some jobs are planned on more day's I only want the first date from today. I get this by using the MIN function in query 2. In the last query I use a left join to combine all my pending jobs with the generated first dates.

How can I do this in ONE query? As I only have reading rights I can't work with temporary tables.

Can someone give me some directions please?

```
**First step**
SELECT
    salesorderplan.plandate,    
    salesorderplan.salesorder
FROM
    salesorderplan
WHERE
    salesorderplan.plandate >= Date();

**second step**
SELECT 
    Min([1estap].plandate) AS firstplandate, [1estap].salesorder
FROM 
    [1estap]
GROUP BY 
    [1estap].salesorder;

**third step**
SELECT
    salesorder.orderno,
    [2estap].firstplandate,
    salesorder.description,
    salesorder.deliverylocname,
    salesorder.deliveryaddress,
    salesorder.deliverycity
FROM
    ((salesorder)
    left join 2estap on (salesorder.objectid = [2estap].salesorder))
WHERE
    salesorder.salesstatus=1
ORDER BY
    salesorder.orderno;
```

I have two tables, the first is called salesorder which contains all my jobs. The second is called salesorderplan which contains all the dates in my planning with the jobnumbers.

```
SALESORDER
objectid description etc
342567   blah blah 
356782   jwz
384512   not in planning yet

SALESORDERPLAN
objectid salesorder plandate 
23451    342567     12-03-2017 
23489    342567     14-04-2017 
23490    356782     13-03-2017 
23496    356782     18-06-2017 
23499    342567     21-08-2017
23499    342567     28-08-2017 
23512    356782     30-08-2017 
23524    356782      2-09-2017
```

I want a list of all my orders. If there is a date in my planning I want the first date after today (that is where I used the MIN fuct for) 
So the outcome should be

```
Result
objectid description             plandate
342567   blah blah               21-08-2017
356782   jwz                     30-08-2017
384512   not in planning yet     no date
```

Comment: You need to show how the tables relates with each other so we can help you to build the query. Show the tables structure and if possible some sample data from the tables and from that sample your desired result.

Comment: What have you actually tried to do, what went wrong, and which Firebird version are you using (your question suggests you are using an ancient version like 1.x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should preface this by saying I don't have experience with firebird, but I do have experience with SQL.  This might work for you:

```
-- **third step**
SELECT
    salesorder.orderno,
    [2estap].firstplandate,
    salesorder.description,
    salesorder.deliverylocname,
    salesorder.deliveryaddress,
    salesorder.deliverycity,
FROM salesOrder LEFT JOIN (
    -- **second step**
    SELECT 
        Min([1estap].plandate) AS firstplandate, [1estap].salesorder
    FROM (
        -- **First step**
        SELECT
            salesorderplan.plandate,    
            salesorderplan.salesorder
        FROM
            salesorderplan
        WHERE
            salesorderplan.plandate >= Date()
    ) [1estap]
    GROUP BY 
        [1estap].salesorder
) [2estap] ON (salesorder.objectid = [2estap].salesorder))
WHERE
    salesorder.salesstatus=1
ORDER BY
    salesorder.orderno;
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @MarkRotteveel, your first two queries can be collapsed into one.  Here's the query with that performed:

```
-- **third step**
SELECT
    salesorder.orderno,
    [2estap].firstplandate,
    salesorder.description,
    salesorder.deliverylocname,
    salesorder.deliveryaddress,
    salesorder.deliverycity,
FROM salesOrder LEFT JOIN (
    -- **first & second steps**
    SELECT 
        Min(plandate) AS firstplandate, salesorder
    FROM salesorderplan
    WHERE
        plandate >= Date()
    GROUP BY 
        salesorder
) [2estap] ON (salesorder.objectid = [2estap].salesorder))
WHERE
    salesorder.salesstatus=1
ORDER BY
    salesorder.orderno;
```

Comment: +1 this should work with Firebird (at least assuming Firebird 2.0 or higher); note that it should be possible to combine the first and second step into one query.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Agreed.  I left it like this so that OP could more easily see what I did here.  I'll add edit with cleaned-up query.

Comment: Does the aggregate query need to exclude salesstatus=1 records from consideration for pulling the Min(plandate)?

Comment: one does not use square brackets in Firebird to escape database objects, a regular double-quote is to be used, like `SELECT salesorder.orderno, "2estap".firstplandate ` or rather just use normal aliases that do not need escaping `SELECT salesorder.orderno, estap2.firstplandate` .... `GROUP BY salesorder) estap2 ON` ....

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Arioch'The.  As I said, I'm no expert in Firebird.